# "How to get the Google video's thumbnail image ? " in PHP or Javascript?

Tags: php, video, thumbnails

I want to use the thumbnail of the Google video's. In PHP or JavaScript function

function getScreen( url, size )
{
  if(url === null){ return ""; }

size = (size === null) ? "big" : size;
  var vid;
  var results;

results = url.match("[\?&]v=([^&#]*)");

vid = ( results === null ) ? url : results[1];

if(size == "small"){

return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+vid+"/2.jpg";
  }else {

return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+vid+"/0.jpg";
  }

}

#### for the you tube vedio

imgUrl_big   = getScreen("uVLQhRiEXZs");

imgUrl_small = getScreen("uVLQhRiEXZs", 'small');

Comment: Could you elaborate on where your problem is? I mean you can simply download the specific site from google via file_get_contents() and then run a regex on the string? Basically google makes it simply for you because the img tag already contains a very nice "clue": 'thumbnail-img';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small script that maybe gets the job done the way you want it:

```
<?php
  $content = file_get_contents("http://video.google.de/?hl=de&tab=wv");
  $regex = '|<img class=thumbnail-img.*?src=(.*?) |';
  preg_match_all($regex, $content, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
  $images = $result[1];
  foreach($images AS $image){
    echo $image;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull an RSS view (parse-able with your favorite XML library) view appending "&output=rss" to any google video search.  The thumbnail for each video can be found in the <media:thumbnail> tag.

[A search for "Stackoverflow", with rss view](http://video.google.com/videosearch?q=stackoverflow&emb=0&aq=f&output=rss).

There seems to be a pattern here.  In that every thumbnail image takes the form of http://*.gvt0.com/vi//default.jpg where * is a digit (I've seen 0 & 3, presumably there are more).  So, if you know the video's id, you can pull the thumbnail without searching for it.  There used to be a better way to do this, but now that Google Video ~= Youtube I think you're stuck with this hack-ish solution.

[The thumbnail of the first image from the above rss feed](http://3.gvt0.com/vi/NWHfY_lvKIQ/default.jpg).

Basically:

```
function getThumbnail($id)
{
  return 'http://0.gvt0.com/vi/'.$id.'/default.jpg';
}
```